# Cannot resolve symbol 'OnMapReadyCallback'

Tags: android, google-maps

[image: MapActivity]

so here's my **build.gradle**

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.christinebpolesti.busartery_driver"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This works fine the other day, I don't know what happened. I even uninstall and installed again android studio because prior to this problem my adb was not located.. So after installing again the AS, I encounter this problem. Can somebody please help.

Comment: You should post the `build.gradle` app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `build.gradle` app and paste this code:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'`

Answer (score 0):

That happens because

```
OnMapReadyCallback
```

is a interface from the package

```
com.google.android.gms.maps
```

so you have to **include dependency for this package for using this interface**

also `Latlng,GoogleMap` are also comes with this package